# How to make sure when I am reading a bufferedReader the line is not empty?

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

I am using a buffered reader to read a file. I need to call trim on all of these lines to pass tests my professor has given us. The problem is there are a few lines that are empty strings, so how I have it set up I am getting a null pointer exception. My biggest question is there away with buffered readers that I can check make sure the line is not an empty String. Thank you for what ever help you have!

```
FileReader fRead = new FileReader(bibleFile);
BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader(fRead);
String line = bRead.readLine();
if (!line.equals("")) {
  line = bRead.readLine().trim();
  while (line != null) {
    /** method * */
    line = bRead.readLine().trim();
  }
}
bRead.close();
```

Comment: `String.trim()` never returns null. The null check should be on the result of `readLine()`.

Comment: `readLine()` only returns null when there are no lines left in the file.  But you should really check this before you start doing things to `line`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the line whether null or not:

```
String str;
while ((str = bRead.readLine()) != null) {
}
```

You need to check whether line is null or not before check it's empty or not